# Does the output voltage depend on the resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis

If I have the function for the output voltage between node 1 and node 2 that is dependent on the input voltage, does R2 play a role in the function or is the output voltage just the Voltage over L1?

*Don't mind the actual values of the parts, it's a general question*
Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxkP01.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is quite basic electronics level so I really expect you to be able to at least **think** about it and tell us what you **think** the answer should be. It doesn't matter if it is wrong because then we will help you to get it right. But now your question is like *what is it* and an answer could be *it is this* and then you would have learned nothing. Next time L1 is a capacitor and you again don't know the answer.

Comment: Clue: what current is flowing through R2 in any scenario?

Comment: Extra hint: what do you use to measure the "output voltage" ?

Comment: Depends on whether you are talking ideal or real world.

Comment: Ok I should have said what my thoughts about this were, will do so the next time. I thought that since it is an open circuit and there can't be a current flowing, there cant be a voltage drop over the resistor so the output voltage must be the same as the voltage over L1. I can conclude that this is true based on the asnwers, at least in an ideal setup, where the resistance of the voltmeter would be infinetly large. It was just bothering me for some reason. I took this example from an old exam and I did not think they would put a "useless" resistor in there.

Comment: @SteveMelons right.. but in reality it's also not quite that simple either.. What if R2 is infinite, or extremely large... Then parasitic impedances between the output pins come into play.

Comment: And it's not a useless resistor... note how much it made you think about the problem, from a teaching point of view it is anything but useless. Further at some point something will be attached across the output, as such you need to understand how that resistance will affect the output.

Comment: That is why I said "useless" instead of uselss.. It did make me think about it but only concerning the task it did not alter the result.

Comment: But thank you anyways, the answers did clear things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is an open loop between node1 and node2, no current flows through R2 resistor so there will not be a voltage drop across it and the voltage between the nodes is equal to the voltage across L1. For instance, most of the voltmeters do not conduct current and form an open loop due to their high resistance. But if there is a current flowing between the node 1 and 2 then there will be a voltage drop on R2 resistor and the output voltage is not equal to the voltage across L1.